# How to prevent autogenerated category and product rewrite urls

Tags: magento2, category, url-rewrite

When I'm importing products or creating categories Magento always automatically generates rewrite urls.

These rewrites are listed at **Admin Backend -> Marketing -> URL Rewrites**.

The category url I want:

```
www.example.com/store-view/category-name
```

What Magento 2 gives me after its autogenerated url rewrite:

```
www.example.com/store-view/catalog/category/view/s/category-name/id/4/
```

I know that I can get rid of the redirect by deleting it at **Admin Backend -> Marketing -> URL Rewrites**. However, I have hundreds of categories and thousands of products and there is no batch delete and I don't want to edit the database because this is unsafe and I would have to do it after each product import.

My questions are:
1. Why is Magento generating such wired urls?
2. How can I prevent autogenerated rewrite urls? Can I do this via config.xml or by writing a plugin (At this point of time I don't know the method that is responsible for autogenerating rewrite urls)?

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue, and it looks like this is a known issue within Magento2 and has not been resolved yet https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5863

Answer (score 0):

Generally magento show the category URL like this.

```
www.example.com/category-name
```

If you just want to add store code into URL, then you need to do this.

1. On the Admin, `System > Settings > Configuration.`
2. On the left panel, under `General`, select `Web`.
3. Open the `URL Options` section.
4. Choose `Yes` in the `Add Store Code` as you need.

After doing this, do caching and then check frontend. It show URL like this.

```
www.example.com/store-code/category-name
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this does not address my issue.